# Python xlrd package issue

Tags: python, xlrd

Is there any way to overcome the next problem:
When using the xlrd package in Python, the value '1' in the excel file is shows as '1.0'.

Now, I am writing a script that should be able to notice the difference, I am using this values as indexes, so '1' and '1.0' are completely different indexes, but I cant find any way to overcome this issue.

Is there something I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a common problem with **xlrd**.
You generally need to convert to int, when the number is actually of *int* type and rest of the times you need it as a *float* itself.

So here is something that works out well in most cases:

```
 int_value = int(float_value)
 if float_value == int_value:
     converted_value = int_value
 else:
     converted_value = float_value
```

**Example**

```
>>> a = 123.0
>>> type(a)
<type 'float'>
>>> b = int(a)
>>> a == b
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while parsing excel files using xlrd. The easiest route that I found was to just convert the known float values to ints. Unless you happen to have the situation, where you don't know the datatype of the field you are parsing.

In that situation, you can try converting to int, and catching the error. For eg:

```
try:
    converted_int = int(float_number)
except Error:
    //log or deal with error here.
```

Answer (score 0):

use `int(some_number)` to convert the number to `integer`.
You can see the documentation for int function from here: [BIF](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)
Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to int using `int(input_number)`. 
An idea to use `isinstance()` method also helps. You can use something like

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
data = []
for row in range(1, sheet.nrows): # skip the header
    l = []
    for column in range(0, sheet.ncols):
        val = sheet.cell(row, column).value
        if isinstance(val,float):
            l.append(int(val))
        else:
            l.append(val)

    data.append(l)

print(data) # [['id101', 1], ['id102', 2], ['id103', 3]]
```